# What's the meaning of "every man for himself"?

Tags: expressions

"In today's society, it is **every man for himself**."

Q. what does "every man for himself" exactly mean?

Is it "Take good care of yourself first other than others"?
Or "Do your job on your own without others' help"?
Or something else?

Comment: Compare *I am **against** tyranny, but I am **for** democracy,* and *Selfish people are only [out] **for** themselves*.

Comment: You're enlightening the meaning of "for" as in "for himself', aren't you? Thank you for your tip:)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to give you (and anyone else who might read this) some useful *background* information so you might be able to figure out the meanings of some similar usages without needing to look them up or ask here every time. Note that your exact cited usage isn't *actually* "short for" [*Every man **must look out** for himself,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22must+look+out+for+himself%22) but that longer version means exactly the same thing....

Comment: To ***look out*** for yourself normally means to be careful, to be "on the lookout" for potential danger (compare the warning cry ***Watch out**!*), whereas to ***look after*** yourself means to ***take care of yourself, tend to your needs***, which is slightly different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Every man for himself" is supposed to have been customarily shouted when a ship was sinking, and means "Each man must save himself from drowning, because nobody else will".

> Definition of every man for himself
>
> Idiom
>
> used to describe a situation in which people do not help each other
> and each person has to take care of himself or herself
>
> As soon as there was a crisis, it was every man for himself.

[Every man for himself (Merriam-Webster Dictionary)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/every%20man%20for%20himself)

Comment: Now I'm completely clear! Thank you for your kindness so much:)